# В каком случае могут быть одинаковые IP адреса

Tags: ip

В каком случаем могут быть одинаковые IP адреса? Было предположение, что при выдаче провайдером динамических IP. Но тогда встаёт такой вопрос какими способами или протоколами это регулируется?

Comment: DHCP сервер выдает

Comment: Провайдер не будет выдавать одинаковые ip, иначе они работать не смогут одновременно. Поясните, в связи с чем возник такой вопрос

Comment: *В каком случаем могут быть одинаковые IP адреса?* Вообще? или интересуют только случаи, когда эта ситуация легитимна?